# How do I stop a group of cells from incrementing within a formula in Excel

Tags: excel

I've tried finding solutions online however no cigar as of yet. Thought about doing this manually but then I wouldn't learn anything.

The formula in question is:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A3,'April 17'!A3:A170,0))
```

I'd like for 'A3:A170' to not increment, however I'm happy having everything else icrement which already is the case.

Comment: `$A$3:$A$170`.... research [absolute vs. relative references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

Comment: Awesome mate! Thanks a bunch!